# Accessing data in PHP object by numeric key

Tags: php, solr

I have the output of a solr queries "highlighting" in an object I don't know how to access it's data. Lets say i want to get back "Black & Red" I've tried:

```
$object->{10304}->color_source_name[0];
$object->{'10304'}->color_source_name[0];
```

Both give me nothing. How do I access the data?

Here's the object i'm referencing below:

```
print_r($object);

SolrObject Object
(
[10304] => SolrObject Object
    (
        [color_source_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Black & Red
            )

        [description] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  with their true identity safely masked.Midcalf Lucha Red
            )

        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sock It To Me Lucha Red Midcalf
            )

        [color] => Array
            (
                [0] => Red
            )

    )

[4075] => SolrObject Object
    (
        [color_source_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Beige/Red
            )

        [description] => Array
            (
                [0] => Very sheer with red tops and Cuban heels and an oh-so-sexy red backseam.  These are designed
            )

        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Two-Tone Red Cuban-Heeled Stockings
            )

        [color] => Array
            (
                [0] => Red
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 3):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/class.solrobject.php `SolrObject` implements `ArrayAccess` so you can use square brackets, e.g.

```
echo $object[4075]['colour_source_name'][0];
```

Comment: i know this SHOULD be possible, but it just never worked. I ended up having to do a foreach loop and pull out the keys that way. Doesn't make sense but that's what happened.

Comment: I can't say. I didn't end up accessing it directly. But like I said i had to pull it out another way via looping thru it.

Comment: @danjfoley can you provide your solution and accept it, so future visitors can benefit from it just in case my reading of the manual is wrong.